# home directory running out of space

Tags: partitioning, home-directory, gparted

My hard disk size is 750 GB
 Out of which only 93 GB is only assigned to home directory and root directory has 600 GB .
The home directory space 99% is in use.

I've installed GParted but when I right click in home directory resize/move option is not hightlighted.

How can I reduce the size of root directory and add space to home directory?

Comment: You need to do this from a live medium like cd/dvd/usb so that they aren't mounted. You'll also likely to need to turn swap off.

Answer (score 0):

As "Elfy" already said, you can just run GParted from the Installation Disc/USB Stick of Ubuntu. I just wanted to add, that, in case that you stored some sensitive Data on your HardDrive, that you should have a Backup before repartitioning. You should have a Backup in general. But sometimes things go wrong when repartitioning and your Files could get lost!

Have a nice day.